# search in a big binary file loading blocks in buffer

Tags: c++, full-text-search, buffer

I want to know the algorithm of searching in a big file by blocks, loading them into memory buffer.

So I have a huge file and will read it to small buffer and scan it for "needle" word:

```
while ( read = fread(buff, buff_size, 1, file) )
   if strstr(buff, needle) print "found!";
```

But what if "needle" in the "hay" will be cut by block border? It will impossible to find.

One solution I see is to read next block fseek'ing it back every time (reducing  offset on length of "needle" string)

```
 offset += read - strlen(needle);
 if (offset > 0) fseek(file, offset ,SEEK_SET);
```

Am I right?

Comment: Is this a binary search? Looks like a linear search.

Comment: Also, please avoid pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that you'll need to handle the case where the search pattern spans two blocks.

You are also right that seek can be one solution.

But there are other solutions which doesn't use seek.

**Solution 1**

A solution could be to copy the last part of the buffer, i.e. `strlen(needle)` to a little buffer capable of holding 2 times `strlen(needle)`.

Then when reading the next block you copy the first part of the new buffer (again `strlen(needle)`) to the little buffer so that it is contatenated with the part from the end of the previous buffer.

Finally you can do a search in the little buffer for niddle.

**Solution 2**

A solution could be to read from file into `buffer + strlen(needle)`, i.e. avoid overwriting the first `strlen(needle)` characters of buffer. The number of characters read from the file must be decreased accordingly (i.e. `buff_size - strlen(needle)`)

When done with a buffer, you copy the last `strlen(needle)` characters to the start of buffer and read more data from the file into `buffer + strlen(needle)`

For the first search in buffer, you'll have to skip the first `strlen(needle)` characters (or make sure they don't match your pattern, e.g. by initialization). Subsequent searches shall search the whole buffer.